# Remotely running a program

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-access

I have Windows Server 2008 and more computers in the domain. I need to run a program from the server on all the other computers, for example to install Kaspersky on the target computers. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You may install programs using Group Policy Objects and MSI files of a program distribution. [Deploying an MSI through GPO](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-gpo.html).

You also have an option to deploy any remote control software e. g. [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com) or schedule programs execution using Task Scheduler.

This question is better suited for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I just heard of [PDQ Deploy](http://www.adminarsenal.com/pdq-deploy/main/) today. Perhaps it could be what you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

While some software can be deployed via Group Policies, most can't. You should investigate tools such as psexec, which will allow you to run pretty much any software on a target machine.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your specific example, Kaspersky Antivirus installs through a deployment console which is installed on the server. The console itself will allow you to deploy the client to as many or as few machines as you like.
It's called the [Kaspersky Administration Kit](http://www.kaspersky.co.uk/administration_kit). Alternatively it has a wizard for configuring Kaspersky which will give you an MSI for deployment using GPOs in Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that this is kind of a necro, but i used powershell to get around this.

Dependencies :

ActiveDirectory Module (Is included in Microsoft RSAT)

psexec.exe from sysinternals.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | where { $_.Name -like "EB*"} | Select Name

foreach ($srv in $Servers){
    $server = $srv.Name
    C:\Sysinternalssuite\psexec.exe \\$server -u DOMAIN\USER -p PASSWORD -h -d #EG: gpupdate.exe "/force" or #powershell.exe "enable-psremoting -force"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with a configuration management tool. In Microsoft's world, System Center Configuration Manager is typically the tool of choice for this, but there are competing products from third parties. This can be used for a range of tasks from operating system deployment, to patching, to compliance reporting, to software deployment.

You can script something in PowerShell or leverage GPO, but both have their limitations.